# Regular expression check to not allow certain characters

Tags: regex

I have a requirement to **not allow** " , \ in the particular string. May i please know on how to write a regular expression.

Eg: employee name = "testName";
I need a pattern to check there are no " , \ **at any position**. Apart from these three characters, rest alll characters should be  allowed.

I am new to regular expression. Kindly help me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The pattern for this is as simple as `^[^",\\]+$`

Explanation:

- `^` start of string

  - `[` start character class

    - `^` any character but the following
    - `",\\` literal `"` or `,` or `\`
  - `]` end character class
  - `+` one or more of the preceeding
- `$` end of string

Answer (score 2):

```js
const pattern = /^[^"\\,]*$/
```

the leading `^` inside `[]` means anything except any chars following ^ sign inside `[]`

Answer (score 1):

You can test if the string does not match these characters :

```js
let isValid = !name.match(/\\|,|"/)    // if ",\ are not in the string
```